# Error: The best overloaded method match for 'LaunchPadLite.Software.Software(int, string, string)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#

Every time I try to run this is red underlines "new Software(name, ID, newPath);" Anyone know how to fix this?

```
 public Software addSoftware()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the application");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the ID");
            int ID = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadKey());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the full path");
            string newPath = Console.ReadLine();
            Software newSoftware = new Software(name, ID, newPath);
            return newSoftware;
        }
```

Comment: check the order of the parameters, the first param should be the int,  and second param is a string.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the method signature is

```
LaunchPadLite.Software.Software(int, string, string)
```

However you are trying to invoke it with

```
string, int, string
```

Check the order of the arguments, pass the correct types and it should work.